# Subtraction in R and how to delete rows without information

Tags: r

how can I subtract 2 rows in R?

I´m trying to subtract these 2 rows, but I can´t.

```
a$carbon_emissions[135,0]- a$carbon_emissions[1,0]
```

On the other hand, how can I delete a row if one specific column has not information?

Thanks!

Comment: You only may subtract numerical variables. Check `str(a)`. For second issue try `a[!is.na(a$carbon_emissions),]`.

Comment: Hello Jay, thanks for answer me. The carbon emission is numerical, but I don´t know which command use to subtract.  $ carbon_emissions: num  236 243 256 272 275 277 281 295 327 327.    The second one done!  Thanks!!

Comment: What are your trying to say with `[135,0]` and `[1,0]` ? Use `a$carbon_emissions[135]- a$carbon_emissions[1]` to subtract `carbon_emissions` of row 1 from that of row 135.

Comment: Indexing starts with 1 in R, so I am not sure what you are trying to do with `a$carbon_emissions[135,0]` A reproducible example along with expected output would help to provide a good solution. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).